# What are the meaning of these sentences?

Tags: grammar

What are the meanings of following sentences:

> 1.You *could* get a better job if you spoke English.
>   2.You *would* get a better job if you spoke English.
>   3.You *could* have got a better job if you had spoken English.
>   4.You *would* have got a better job if you had spoken English.

I'm confused here because they're similar to me . Could you please make clear meanings of these sentences?

Comment: 1 &2 are said hypothetically, with 1 being less certain. 3&4 meant the claim would be true if the condition was true, with 3 being less certain.

Comment: And 3 and 4 should be using "gotten", not "got".

Comment: You are asking two questions that have many points, **would* vs. *could*" and simple vs. perfect tenses. Each should be asked separately. Also "can't distinguish" isn't really helpful, because we can't know what that means.

Answer (score 2):

All four sentences are conditionals. Let's start with the first two.

1. If you spoke English, you could get a better job.
2. If you spoke English, you would get a better job.

The only difference is "would" vs "could". **Would** means it's likely or certain you'll get a better job. **Could** means it's possible.

---

The last two sentences use a stronger form of the past tense. Technically, they use **past perfect** instead of **past simple**.

1. If you had spoken English, you could have got a better job.
2. If you had spoken English, you would have got a better job.

These two sentences imply that the possibility of getting a better job is already in the past. Kind of like saying the person missed out.

---

Technically speaking, the first two sentences are called **second degree conditional**, and the last two are called **third degree conditional**.

Comment: Are first two sentences is used in present tense situations?

Comment: You can use the present tense by saying "If you speak English, you can get a better job". The sentences are all suited to different contexts.

Comment: Let's say a Korean man and his wife move to America. The husband might tell his wife, "If you spoke English you could get a better job". This could be a way of encouraging his wife to learn English. It also implies that his wife doesn't know English.

Comment: A different example. A husband tells his wife, "If you speak English they will understand you". This is also conditional. It implies the wife knows how to speak English. It uses the present tense.